# Is my formula for the coefficients of $\prod_{i=1}^n (x-a_i)$ correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, products, cyclotomic-polynomials

I tried to figure out an other expression of the product $$\prod_{i=1}^n (x-a_i)$$
and I ended up to the expression
$$\sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i$$ where
$$ c_i = \left(-1\right)^{\delta_{n-i\pmod 2} (\{1\})}
\sum_{j_k=0, \, j_k \neq k_l,\forall l\neq k \,|l,k\in\{i\}_{i=0}^n}^n\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-i} a_{j_k}\right)$$
where
$$\{ a_{j_k}\}_{j_k=1}^n = \{ a_i\}_{i=1}^n   and \, a_{j_0}=1 $$
$$ for \, \, some \, \, integers \, \, \{a_i\}_{i=1}^n \, \, and \, \, a \, \, natural \,\,  number \,\,  n$$
Is it true?

(Excuse me but I haven't learned to use LaTeX so the formula might be difficult to read. Thank you for your time in advance! )

Comment: a good way to find the coefficients is to think of this product as a polynomial with roots $a_i$ and then by vietas theorem you can do the rest

Comment: By Vieta's formulae $$
c_i  = ( - 1)^{n - i} \sum\limits_{1 \le j_1  < j_2  <  \cdots  < j_{n - i}  \le n} {\left( {\prod\limits_{k = 1}^{n - i} {a_{j_k } } } \right)} .
$$

Comment: Thank you both very much for your explanations. These were really useful !

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to write that product as a polynomial in the $\{1,\dots , x^n, \dots\}$ base. In fact the complexity of the problem is the same to compute the inverse of a specific matrix.

If you write that product as $\sum_{i=0}^nc_i x^i$ for some appropriate $c_i$, then that coefficients must satisfy the linear system

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
1 & a_1 & \dots & a_1^n \\
\dots \\ 
1 & a_n & \dots & a_n^n\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}c_0\\
\vdots \\
c_n \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}\prod_{i=1}^na_i\\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0 \end{bmatrix}$

And so the solution is

$\begin{bmatrix}c_0\\
\vdots \\
c_n \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
1 & a_1 & \dots & a_1^n \\
\dots \\ 
1 & a_n & \dots & a_n^n\\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}\prod_{i=1}^na_i\\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0 \end{bmatrix}$